# How to solve Openssl issue log created in Xcart?

Tags: x-cart

Am newbie to Xcart,I can't identify when below log error created and how to solve these error.

```
HTTPS module: openssl
    Error message:
Request URI: /cart.php
```

Please tell me why this error created and How to avoid these log error in Xcart.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your https module
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:General_Options#Miscellaneous
http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/admin/configuration.php#tr_httpsmod

The recommended is libcurl
The setting name is 'Preferred HTTPS module'

Also make sure you can open a page like https://your_site.com/cart.php